# Loss of precision error

Tags: java, switch-statement, precision

I'm new to Java and am writing some code for a simple program.

This program will ask the user how many classes they have taken, and then for a letter grade and credit hours for each class.

I am having plenty of trouble writing this program.. I think I've got it close but I'm still struggling with a few things.  Specifically I am being given a "loss of precision" error, but I was under the impression that those only show up when using Math.pow or floats.

Here's what I've got:

import java.util.Scanner;
public class GPA

```
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
   {

    Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter number of classes: ");
    int numberClasses = kbReader.nextInt();

    int i;

      for (i = 0; i < numberClasses; i++)
      {

  System.out.print("Enter letter grade of class: ");
      int letterGrade = kbReader.nextInt();

  System.out.print("Enter credit hour of class: ");
  int creditHour = kbReader.nextInt();

int totalCreditForGPA;
int totalCreditHours;

switch (letterGrade)
    {
   case 'A':
   case 'a': totalCreditForGPA = totalCreditForGPA + (creditHour * 4.0);
         totalCreditHours =  totalCreditHours + creditHour;
         break;
  case 'B':
  case 'b':  totalCreditForGPA = totalCreditForGPA + (creditHour * 3.0);
         totalCreditHours =  totalCreditHours + creditHour;
         break;
  case 'C':
  case 'c':  totalCreditForGPA = totalCreditForGPA + (creditHour * 2.0);
         totalCreditHours =  totalCreditHours + creditHour;
         break;
  case 'D':
  case 'd':  totalCreditForGPA = totalCreditForGPA + (creditHour * 1.0);
         totalCreditHours =  totalCreditHours + creditHour;
         break;
  case 'F':
  case 'f':  totalCreditForGPA = totalCreditForGPA + (creditHour * 0.0);
         totalCreditHours =  totalCreditHours + creditHour;
         break;
  default:
         System.out.println("Invalid letter grade.");
    }
  }

int GPA = totalCreditforGPA;
System.out.println("Your GPA is " + GPA);
   }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advace.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: "I was under the impression that those only show up when using Math.pow or floats." Obviously you were mistaken about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:
    1. you are accessing loop local variable outside the loop.
2. you are casting double result to int that is not possible, you have to use explicit cast or use the type double for prevent precision loss.

```
     package com.general.generics;
    import java.util.Scanner; 
    public class GPA

    {
      public static void main(String[] args)

   {

    Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter number of classes: ");
    int numberClasses = kbReader.nextInt();

    int i;
    int totalCreditForGPA=0; //these should be defined outside loop and should be double for precision.
    int totalCreditHours=0;
      for (i = 0; i < numberClasses; i++)
      {

      System.out.print("Enter letter grade of class: ");
          int letterGrade = kbReader.nextInt();

      System.out.print("Enter credit hour of class: ");
      int creditHour = kbReader.nextInt();



    switch (letterGrade)
        {
       case 'A':
       case 'a': totalCreditForGPA = (int) (totalCreditForGPA + (creditHour * 4.0)); //result should be type to int or use totalCreditForGPA as double
             totalCreditHours =  totalCreditHours + creditHour;
             break;
      case 'B':
      case 'b':  totalCreditForGPA = (int) (totalCreditForGPA + (creditHour * 3.0));
             totalCreditHours =  totalCreditHours + creditHour;
             break;
      case 'C':
      case 'c':  totalCreditForGPA = (int) (totalCreditForGPA + (creditHour * 2.0));
             totalCreditHours =  totalCreditHours + creditHour;
             break;
      case 'D':
      case 'd':  totalCreditForGPA = (int) (totalCreditForGPA + (creditHour * 1.0));
             totalCreditHours =  totalCreditHours + creditHour;
             break;
      case 'F':
      case 'f':  totalCreditForGPA = (int) (totalCreditForGPA + (creditHour * 0.0));
             totalCreditHours =  totalCreditHours + creditHour;
             break;
      default:
             System.out.println("Invalid letter grade.");
        }
      }

    int GPA = totalCreditForGPA;
    System.out.println("Your GPA is " + GPA);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, others here gave me some help but I knew I had multiple issues you and showed me all of them.

Comment: no problem man! i sensed you are really new to programming so i helped like this.

Answer (score 1):

These lines cause your loss of precision problem

```
totalCreditForGPA = totalCreditForGPA + (creditHour * 4.0);
totalCreditHours =  totalCreditHours + creditHour;
```

You're multiplying an int by a double, which upcasts to a double, that you're adding to an int which still keeps it a double, which cannot be stored in an int variable. The solution would be to store your variables as doubles, or to multiply by integers (4 instead of 4.0, for example). Remember to fix the problem everywhere you're multiplying with a double, meaning in all the cases of your switch statement.